# Iteration in R for different files

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, iteration

I need something that for me is a bit difficult but it's very easy for sure for an R expert programmer. I need to iterate my script using information contained in a dataframe.
Dataframe is something like

```
   pdb       range
1 1a7s_A     78:81
2 1b9o_A     50:53
3 1b9o_A    99:102
4 1bkr_A     27:30
5 1c0p_A 1179:1182
6 1c75_A     42:45
```

I need to iterate my script for each row

```
 pdb <- read.pdb("1a7s_A.pdb") ## here I need to read my pdb file 
    pdb <- atom.select(pdb, resno = 78:81, verbose = T, value = T) ## here I have to put the value in range col

... #my script instruction

table <- data.frame("pdb" = "1a7s_A", ## here I have to insert the name file again 
                    "res" = "78:81",  ## here the range 
                    "omega2" = omega2, "phi2" = phi2,  "psi2" = psi2,
                    "omega3" = omega3, "phi3" = phi3, "psi3" = psi3)
```

At the end, I need a df with all the info from iteration of each file.

It's sure that I will set as working directory the one containing all files to be read. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, create a read-function like

```
readTableFromRange <- function(tableName,rangeString) {
  filename <- paste0(tableName,".pdb") #get the filename by appendong the pdb-ending
  pdb <- read.pdb(filename)
  rangeNumeric <- eval(parse(text=rangeString)) #getting the range as a numeric vector by evaluating the string as a r-command
  pdb <- atom.select(pdb, resno = rangeNumeric, verbose = T, value = T)
  
  #Enter your script here...
  
  return(data.frame("pdb" = tableName,
                    "res" = rangeString,  
                    "omega2" = omega2, "phi2" = phi2,  "psi2" = psi2,
                    "omega3" = omega3, "phi3" = phi3, "psi3" = psi3))
}
```

Knowing that your dataframe is called `pa`, you can apply this function like

```
tableList <- Map(readTableFromRange,pa$pdb,pa$range)
```

to get a list of tables and finally you can bind them all together with

```
do.call("rbind",tableList )
```

Comment: I don't know why but it seems is not working because I don't get en error but I don't have anything in my environment

Comment: the df cotaining the info to be read is called "pa". Could you be so gentle su edit your anser knowing my df name?

Comment: changed my answer. It had to be done in the call of `Map`. In your question, your wrote `... #my script instruction`. This has to come in my function where you find `#Enter your script here...`. It should be something that takes the `pdb` and calculates `omega2,omega3,phi2,phi3,psi2,psi3`.

Comment: I can see if it works starting from read.pdb, that's why I didn't put following comands. So what I have to do with your answer is just copy and run it?