# How to iteratively read in files in R and save the content of each file in a different variable without using Pandas?

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, data-science, file-handling

I have a scenario in which I have a bunch of files with the same naming except one number in the name. I want to create as many variables as I have files. So far, my code looks like this:

```
for(i in 1:26)
{
  if ( i <= 9 )
  {
      OutFile=paste0("Iterated.Filename0",i,".out")
      out <- read.table(OutFile, header = FALSE, sep="\t", dec=".", na.strings = "NA")
  } else {
      OutFile=paste0("Iterated.Filename",i,".out")
      out <- read.table(OutFile, header = FALSE, sep="\t", dec=".", na.strings = "NA")
  }
}
```

(The difference before and after the `else` statement is the `0` after "Filename")

The problem is that the finally created `out` variable  is (a) just one variable and not the variables `out1` to `out26` and (b) it does not hold the concatenated data of all the read in files, but just the data of the 26th `.out` file.

So my question is: How to read multiple files in R in a way that the content of each file gets stored in a different variable?
And especially how to do this without using Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible using built-in functions is as follows:

```
paths <- sprintf("Iterated.Filename%02d.out", 1:26)
out <- lapply(paths, read.table, header=FALSE, sep="\t", dec=".", na.strings="NA")
```

The variable `out` here is a list containing 26 datasets.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is way more helpful than the answer to an [almost similar previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66105141/iteration-in-r-for-different-files) and it solved my problem - thanks!

Comment: May I add: How to
`for(i in 1:26) {head(out[[i]])}`
?

Comment: `lapply` is like a loop in the sense that it loops (but implicitly) over each element passed as the first argument. I advise you to have a look at its help page (`help("lapply")`).  to get the header for each dataset, you can  use `lapply(out, head)`; in this case, `lapply` will apply the function `head` on each element in `out`, which is a list containing all
the datasets.  you can also pass the `head` arguments to `lapply` like in `lapply(out, head, n=2)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your advice as well as explanation of `lapply`!